# How to specify time in kaltura api

Tags: kaltura

I am trying to call liveReport service of kaltura but I m not sure how to specify time in the request filters. It asks time to be in int format but when i canver time in milli seconds I get long value, but API is expecting int value.

can anyone provide help in this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to `livereports.getreport` service then `fromTime` & `toTime` properties expect an integer timestamp in seconds. You can also provide a timestamp that is lower then `315360000` seconds and it will be treated relative to `NOW`, so `-1440` will be converted to `NOW - 1440`

Seems like other report services are expecting an integer that is created using conversion of date format `YYYYMMDD` to integer, so for May 18th, 2015 you would send 20150318.

Comment: Thanks Roman for reply. But I m not able to access livereports.getreport and livereports.getEvents APIs, It always say that, Failed to get live reports, no detailed cause of exception is shown. I m not sure what i m missing, I added, fromDate, toDate, entryIds in report filter params but, not able to get it.

Comment: Try the kaltura.org forums http://forum.kaltura.org/, with more details about the issue that you are experiencing.